# How to couple img to body?

Tags: css

1. I need to couple top border image to top border body as you can see in the left side.
2. I need to cupole the "NEXT PICTURE :"  to right.
   Thanks.
   You know something strange happens images switch in chrom  slowly and stop in firefox there is no problem with velocity
   [my site.](http://www.centerwow.com/comics/comics.html)

Comment: And..? What have you tried? Where are you having problems?

Comment: I try absualte position and fix position and relative position and float

Answer (score 2):

you can use the background properties in css

```
body {
   background-image: url(someimage.png);
   background-position: top left;
   background-repeat:repeat-x;  (or no-repeat if you only want it once)
   background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

this will tile an image along the top of your page (use **background-attachment:fixed;** if you want it to always be at the top of the screen)

[Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

You could put your next image in a div:

```
<div style="text-align:right">
    NEXT PICTURE :<img id="scroll_me" alt="NEXT PICTURE :" src="img/next.jpg">
</div>
```

this would align your image with the right hand edge of the browser window.

Try that and see how you get on, there are other things you can do, but let me know how you on.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `<p>NEXT PICTURE..</p>` to below (outside) your "container" div, and remove the two `<br>` at the top.
That will do the trick.